# conjugate gradient: monotone decreasing krylov sequence of function values

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

On p.10 of Boyd's [notes](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/11-conj_grad_slides.pdf) on Conjugate Gradient, he says that a property of the Krylov sequence is that $f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k)$ where $f(x) := \tfrac 12 x^T A x + b^T x$. I tried expanding this as
\begin{align}
f(x_{k+1}) = f(x_k + \alpha_k p_k) = f(x_k) + f(\alpha_k p_k) + 2\alpha_k x_k^T A p_k
\end{align}
but don't see how $f(\alpha_k p_k) + 2\alpha_k x_k^T A p_k \leq 0$.

Comment: 1) You have a sign problem in your $f$. 2) What exactly is not clear? 3) To prove the properties of CG is quite technical so why not to start with any decent book on iterative methods or the [original paper](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/049/jresv49n6p409_A1b.pdf)?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: thanks for your note! 1) don't think the sign of $b$ should matter, I guess my $b$ is Boyd's $-b$; 2) how can I derive the property that $f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k)$? My approach was to simply expand, but I wasn't able to make progress; 3) thanks for the orig paper -- I'll take a look later this afternoon! I asked just in case I was missing something obvious with my approach.

Comment: The sign of $b$ of course matters. $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx$ is minimized by $x_*=A^{-1}b$, while $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx$ is minimized by $x_*=-A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Ya, but that doesn't affect the validity of $f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k)$, which is what I'm considering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the correct $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx$ and using $r_k=b-Ax_k$, the fact that $r_k^Tp_k=r_k^Tr_k$ (see (5:4a) in the original paper), and the definition of $\alpha_k=r_k^Tr_k/p_k^TAp_k$, we have
$$
f(x_{k+1})=f(x_k)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha_k^2 p_k^TAp_k-\alpha_k r_k^Tp_k=f(x_k)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(r_k^Tr_k)^2}{p_k^TAp_k}.
$$
Since $A$ is SPD,
$$
f(x_k)-f(x_{k+1})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(r_k^Tr_k)^2}{p_k^TAp_k}>0.
$$